# TestCafe Sudio setting different timeout, when recording

Tags: testing, automated-tests, devexpress, e2e-testing, testcafe

The problem is specific to the recording. I found timeouts settings in the browser properties of the TestCafe Studio and they work when I press "Run Test" button. However, whenever I press "Record test" the editor seems to ignore my settings and I get the request timeout error:

`Failed to complete a request to 'address.com' within the timeout period. The problem may be related to local machine's network or firewall settings, server outage, or network problems that make the server inaccessible.`

I tried changing the recording settings, but they don't seem to work either.

The site is up and working, just takes a while to load.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, TestCafe Studio does not support the same settings in recording mode as in run mode.

As a workaround, temporarily place the `await t.wait(timeout)` function at the beginning of the test.

Comment: This doesn't work as t.wait() is executed after the timeout error occurs

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a workaround for you. It appears that solving this problem requires tampering with the TestCafe Studio source code. As soon as we add the necessary options, we will let you know.